# html5 canvas, need to double size but still fit to screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 2 canvases which are sized like so:

```
backgroundCanvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
backgroundCanvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
modelCanvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
modelCanvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

This is great for what I need, but I've decided that I want to put a permanent zoom out on everything by 2 times. I could go in and manually resize and redo all the functionality, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to just double the size of the canvas, but still fit it to screen so that everything is smaller and I have more room to work with.

I tried to resize like this

```
backgroundCanvas.width = document.body.clientWidth * 2;
backgroundCanvas.height = document.body.clientHeight * 2;
modelCanvas.width = document.body.clientWidth * 2;
modelCanvas.height = document.body.clientHeight * 2;
```

which is close to what I'm trying to do, but I want it to scale down and fit to the screen instead of adding a scroller to view the rest of the canvas.

Comment: You can use `context.scale(0.50,0.50)` on both canvases and subsequent drawings will be reduced in scale by 50%.

Comment: Very nice, that fixes it thanks! I'd upvote you if I had the privelege.